# Is there a way to continuously move an object in P5 via user input?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm pretty sure after looking through the documentation that this isn't what the framework is intended to do, but I've got a student I'm tutoring who really wants to move an object drawn on a P5 canvas using input, like using the arrow keys.
What I was able to figure out is the following:

```
let value = 0;
function setup() {
  // Create a canvas with a specified width and height
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  // Fill in background color
  background("blue");
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  translate(value, value, value);
    translate(150, 150, 150)
  rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    
}

function keyPressed() {
    while(true) {
         if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
            value = 20;
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, this uses an infinite loop and is therefore less than ideal. Does anyone know of a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system (Chrome, MacOS), `keyPressed` is called repeatedly if I hold the left-arrow key. Below is a really simple example. Focus into the snippet and hold down your left arrow key - observe that the xPos decreases every frame.

You need to actually *do something* in your `keyPressed` method. Right now, the value is just being assigned repeatedly, and definitely, you don't want to have an infinite loop.

For the record, according to [the docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed), `keyPressed` isn't guaranteed to work this way on all systems, so you may need more complex logic depending on what system(s) you want to run this on.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 360);
}

let xPos = 100;
function draw() {
    background(0,0,255);
    fill(255,0,0);
    ellipse(xPos,50,10,10);
}

function keyPressed(event) {
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
    xPos -= 1;
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW) {
    xPos += 1;
  }

  // this prevents default browser behavior
  event.preventDefault();
  return false; 
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.3.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If `keyPressed()` doesn't work as desired on some systems/browsers/configurations you can use the `keyIsDown()` function to check the keyboard status and update your `xPos` from within the `draw()` function. Ironically the documentation for `keyIsDown()` has this precise use case as an example: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea how I didn't catch that I was assigning the value repeatedly and not incrementing it. I guess I need more sleep...or just to not try and cobble together something for a student from a framework I know nothing about. Cleary either or both fried my brain. I also appreciate that knowledge on the inconsistency with keyPressed(), and the alternative of using keyIsDown().

Answer (score 0):

```
let acl;
let pos;
let value = 0;

function setup() {
  acl = createVector(0,0);
  pos = createVector(0,0);
  // Create a canvas with a specified width and height
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  // Fill in background color
  background("blue");
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(pos.x, pos.y, 20, 20);
  pos.add(acl);
    
}

function keyPressed() {
    
         if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
            acl.set(-1,0)
        }
  if(keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW){
    acl.set(1,0)
  }
  
    
}
```